# How can I make a scrollable list of textboxes?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, textbox, scroll

In my Winforms program the user chooses a combobox value of 2-16 and I would like to generate a corresponding number of textboxes when they press a button, preferably in a scrollable list to keep the form a smaller manageable size. Is this possible?

For those suggesting a flowlayout, how would I add textboxes based on the number chosen in my combobox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the textboxes to a FlowLayountPanel. Make sure you set the AutoScroll property to true:

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();

        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
            return;

        int numberOfTextBoxes = int.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTextBoxes; ++i)
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a FlowLaoyutPanel and when you  click the button, add manually  the textboxes to the FlowLayoutPanel

Answer (score 1):

You can add your TextBoxes into a [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) and set its property AutoScroll to true.